# FullCalendar: borderColor/backgroundColor not working for month view

Tags: javascript, events, vuejs3, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

[image: Events for Week View]

[image: Events for Month View]

In Fullcalendar,
I have used eventDataTransform to set borderColor & backgroundColor.
For Month view event's borderColor & backgroundColor is not taking effect.

i am expecting to take borderColor/backgroundColor effect for month view.

Current event object:

```json
events = [{
    title: 'Timed Event',
    start: '2020-06-23T16:00:00+00:00',
    borderColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}]
```

Please suggest some solution for the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: events = [{
    title: 'Timed Event',
    start: '2020-06-23T16:00:00+00:00',
    borderColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}]

i am using this event format to set color for event. it is not working for month view.

Comment: setting "display": "block" for event, let us set color for the month view event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we use event's **display** property to "**block**",
then it sets the **backgroundColor** and **borderColor** of the event for all views, including month view.

Example:

```json
events = [{
    title: 'Timed Event',
    start: '2020-06-23T16:00:00+00:00',
    display: 'block',
    borderColor: 'red',
    backgroundColor: 'green'
}]
```